# Filter a table's records based on its other records

Tags: sql-server

First, I apologize if the title won't make sense but below is the detailed scenario.

Say I have a `document_revision` table

```
id   document_id  phase_id  user_id
1    1            3         1
2    1            2         1
3    1            1         1
4    2            3         2
5    2            2         2
```

where `phase_id` is: transcribe = 3; proof = 2; and submit = 1.

I would like to write a query where I can filter the revision records where I will disregard a proof phase if the same user did the transcribe and proof. So the output would be:

```
id   document_id  phase_id  user_id
1    1            3         1
3    1            1         1
4    2            3         2
```

I've been struggling for hours figuring out a query for this but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want the phase 3 for any case where a user_id was involved in phase 2 and 3, then one way you could do this is with `ROW_NUMBER()`, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Document_ID INT, Phase_ID INT, [User_ID] INT);

INSERT @T (Document_ID, Phase_ID, [User_ID]) VALUES
(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2);

SELECT ID, Document_ID, Phase_ID, [User_ID]
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Document_ID, [User_ID], CASE WHEN Phase_ID IN (2, 3) THEN 2 ELSE Phase_ID END ORDER BY Phase_ID DESC)
    FROM @T
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick. I didn't know `ROW_NUMBER()` can be this useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @document_revision TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    document_id INT,
    phase_id INT,
    user_id INT
);

INSERT INTO @document_revision
(document_id, phase_id, user_id)
VALUES  
    (1, 3, 1), 
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 3, 2),
    (2, 2, 2),
    -- To test a scenario where there is a proof and a submit with no transcribe phases and same document
    (3, 2, 3), 
    (3, 1, 3),
    -- To test a scenario where there is a transcribe and a submit with no proof phases and same document
    (4, 3, 4), 
    (4, 1, 4),
    -- To test a scenario where there is a proof and a submit with no transcribe phase (for document_id 5) but different document and same user as above 
    (5, 2, 4);

SELECT  dr.id
      , dr.document_id
      , dr.phase_id
      , dr.user_id 
FROM @document_revision AS dr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                    FROM @document_revision AS temp 
                    -- Same user
                    WHERE temp.user_id = dr.user_id 
                        -- Same document
                        AND temp.document_id = dr.document_id
                        -- To check if there is already a transcribe phase_id with the same user_id and document_id
                        AND temp.phase_id = 3
                        -- -- To check if there is already a proof phase_id with the same user_id and document_id
                        AND dr.phase_id = 2 )
```

results:

```
id  document_id phase_id    user_id
1   1           3           1
3   1           1           1
4   2           3           2
6   3           2           3 
7   3           1           3
8   4           3           4
9   4           1           4
10  5           2           4
```

Comment: It may help if you explain your answer some. What was the problem with the OP's code? How does this fix it?